# what is wrong with using List.AddRange(Array) method in c#?

Tags: c#

program in c# ,create a new array(temp) has different size from mp4v(large array) then copy  this array(temp) to List (a)

program is:

```
 {

        int size; int i = 0;

        Int32 [] mp4v=new Int32 [10]{1,12,1,2,11,1,10,4,1,5};

        List<Int32> a = new List<Int32>();

        Int32[] sz = new Int32[] { 3, 3, 4 };



        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
         {
            size = sz[k];

            Int32[] temp = new Int32[size];

            Array.Copy(mp4v, i, temp, 0, size);

            a.AddRange(temp); 

            i = i + size;
         }

        for ( i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("0", a[i]);
```

}

```
  output :


        0

        0

        0

        0

        0

        0

        0

        0

        0

        0
```

what is wrong in  this program, the result must be like this:

1

12

1

2

11

1

10

4

1

5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `Console.WriteLine( "{0}", a[i] )`. The string `"0"` will output 0 everytime, and to use parameter replacement the syntax is `{x}` where x is the parameter index in the list

Comment: thank you so much,but using of AddRange method correctly in this program to copy array to list  ??